# Android Studio: Error: <identifier> expected error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a rookie to programming. I've been trying to build an app and been getting these errors as seen in the screenshot. I've tried the "Invalid Caches/Restart" but it didn't help. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

EDIT: Sorry for earlier ignorance. I've added the code snippets.

Login.Java:

```
package com.example.ankit.mrestro;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button blogin;
    EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    TextView RegisterHere,Skip;
    UserLocalStorage userLocalStorage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        RegisterHere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterHere);
        Skip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Skip);

        blogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);
        blogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        RegisterHere.setOnClickListener(this);
        Skip.setOnClickListener(this);

        userLocalStorage= new UserLocalStorage(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.blogin:
            User user= new User(null, null);
            userLocalStorage.storeUserData(user);
         userLocalStorage.SetUserLoggedIn(true);

            break;

        case R.id.RegisterHere:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
            break;
        case R.id.Skip:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/screen1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:textColor="#A9A9A9A9"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Username"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:textColor="#A9A9A9A9"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Password"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@android:dimen/thumbnail_width"
            android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Login"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Register"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:text="Skip"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Please post the code as text so it may help other users in the future. The image link will inevitably break.

Comment: Mate, please post the layout file so we can inspect it, and rather than the image, post the code snippet which causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your activity_login.xml to ensure that the ID's you are trying to reference are linked to your UI elements in the layout file. It seems like you are trying to link the class level variable to itself in the findViewById() instead of linking the variable to the ID's in the layout file of the corresponding UI elements.

EDIT:
None of your UI elements (EditText fields, Buttons, or even LinearLayouts) have ID's associated with them.  You can either double click the elements when viewing activity_login.xml in the 'Desgin' view to set an ID for the specific element.  Otherwise, you can define an ID for the element in the 'Properties' window or explicitly write out `android:id="@+id/yourIDHere"` in the 'Text' view of the layout file.  Whatever you decide to make your ID, you then must call that in name in findViewById() like so: `findViewById(R.id.yourIDHere);`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've created a package with name "new". Renaming helped.